# Images breaking in production in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, heroku, cloud9-ide

I have deployed my app to heroku using Cloud9 after I changed my database from sqlite3 to postgres. my app hasn't been behaving well after that. For example images in production break after two or three hour from uploading, it is bad. I also have to start the PostgreSQL every couple hour in order to be able to use development `sudo service postgresql start`.

This is my `database.yml`:

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: 5
  username: <%= ENV['USERNAME'] %>
  password: <%= ENV['PASSWORD'] %>
  host:     <%= ENV['IP'] %>

development:
  <<: *default
  database: sample_app_development

test:
  <<: *default
  database: sample_app_test

production:
  <<: *default
  database: sample_app_production
```

I also heard that it has to do with `production.rb`, so here is mine:

```
    Rails.application.configure do

  config.cache_classes = true

  config.eager_load = true

  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true


  config.serve_static_files = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?


  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier

  config.assets.compile = true


  config.assets.digest = true


  config.log_level = :debug


  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new

  config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false
end
```

FYI, in this app users who sign up are able to upload images to the app, so I just can't save the pictures that I want only.

Comment: Where are you saving your assets? Is it somewhere persistent between deployments? Heroku will trash your instances if they become idle and take with it all the temporary data you've accumulated.

Comment: Have you added this `config.serve_static_assets = true` in application.rb and the rails_12factor gem?

Comment: @tadman I am not really sure where is it saved! I am assuming in public/system/posts/images ?

Comment: @KaranShah rails_12factor gem is already added but not the other one! Just added it to my application.rb

Comment: Did it work? if yes, I can post an answer for you to accept?

Comment: It works for the first couple of hours then break again! so if you think that's that will solve the issue, post an answer and I will let you know if it worked

Comment: could you please check(or show us here) one example of broken path, that you do get to see from from source html or browser developer/debug tool

Comment: @KaranShah It still did not work. I believe I figured out the problem and that is once sudo service postgresql stops all the pictures go away!

Comment: Did u install pgsql on heroku ? Ideally you should be using the pgsql addon

Comment: @AmolPujari sure, here it is! http://i.imgur.com/16ylX1V.png

Comment: @KaranShah No, how do i add this! FYI, i am using Cloud9 for development the app! Does this has to do with it?

Comment: I've added the answer, do accept it of it works for you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are not sure about the path of your uploaded files, I believe your problem lies there.
I have not used Heroku much, but from their [article](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem):

> Each dyno gets its own ephemeral filesystem, with a fresh copy of the most recently deployed code. During the dyno’s lifetime its running processes can use the filesystem as a temporary scratchpad, but no files that are written are visible to processes in any other dyno and any files written will be discarded the moment the dyno is stopped or restarted. For example, this occurs any time a dyno is replaced due to application deployment and approximately once a day as part of normal dyno management.

so if your images are uploaded to file system of code, they are not visible to other process or it will be trashed after dyno is replaced because when heroku replace a dyno, It considers only files which were deployed in last deployment. and that does not have the uploaded images.

So I suggest you to use a CDN like AWS S3.

Comment: I believe I figured out the problem and that is once sudo service postgresql stops all the pictures go away, `sudo service postgresql start!`

Comment: @hekmat If they're trashing your dyno it doesn't matter what services are on it. You need to use the Heroku supported persistent database if that's the case.

Comment: apparently that is also not the issue, pictures just broke again even when the postgresql is on! However, I found out that one of the pictures that is saved in public/systems/posts/images in development never breaks but all the other ones that are added in production breaks!

Comment: here is a picture of what it looks like! http://i.imgur.com/16ylX1V.png

Comment: As I explained above, that picture saved in posts/images in development never breaks because you deploy that file to heroku and heroku considers it as a part of core source files. Pictures uploaded in productions are kept till dyno is alive. consider using S3 or as @tadman suggested. PS: I have only used S3 in heroku, no persistence database.

Comment: I believe you are right! let me try it out! Is there a good tutorial that I can follow i order to add it to a pre-existing app? I found that one but I don't feel like it applies! http://lifesforlearning.com/uploading-images-with-carrierwave-to-s3-on-rails/

Comment: There is a small and simple documentation of official github repo. https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave#using-amazon-s3

Answer (score 0):

Your problem has twofold issues, the first of them being trying to install PGSql on Heroku directly.

Understand that unlike a shared server of Digital ocean or AWS, Heroku is a PaaS (Platform as a Service) and you cannot put anything on the heroku server apart from your rails app. You have to use them through [add-ons](https://elements.heroku.com/addons).

Adding PGSql has its own add on too, it will automatically take periodic backups for you and will be much more optimised to do DB operations.

Learn more about it here:
https://elements.heroku.com/addons/heroku-postgresql

Also, Heroku does not encourage storing static assets on the server as it recycles them every time you restart your server so you will have to compile your assets everytime you deploy. To make this better, upload them to either a CDN or S3.